# Swift 4 uploading images to Firebase

Tags: firebase, xcode9, swift4

Good afternoon everyone, I am trying to upload an image to firebase and display back on a cell..I have just about all the content working except the image (i cant get rid of the error).

[Here is the error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXV0z.png)

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Posts' with an argument list of type '(postImageStringUrl: String, content: String!, postId: String)'

```
    //[Save Image]
    // Create data in the server
    let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.addedImage.image!, 0.5)
    let metadata = StorageMetadata()
    metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"

    let postId = "\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)\(NSUUID().uuidString)"
   // Create a reference to the file you want to upload
    let imagePath = "postImages\(postId)/postPic.jpg"

    storageRef.child(imagePath).putData(data!, metadata: metadata) { (metadata, error) in
        if error == nil {
            let postRef = self.databaseRef.child("posts").childByAutoId()
            let post = Posts(postImageStringUrl: String (describing: metadata!.downloadURL()), content: descriptionTextView.text, postId: postId)
            postRef.setValue(post.toAnyObject())
        }else{
            print(error.debugDescription)
        }
    }
    //[Save Image]
```

Here is my postViewController

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage
```

struct Posts {

`var postImageStringUrl: String!
var department: String!
var content: String!
var username: String!
var postId: String!
var ref: DatabaseReference?
var key: String!


init(postImageStringUrl: String, department: String, content: String, username: String,postId: String, key: String = ""){

    self.postImageStringUrl = postImageStringUrl
    self.department = department
    self.content = content
    self.username = username
    self.postId = postId
    self.key = key
    self.ref = Database.database().reference()


}

init(snapshot: DataSnapshot){

    let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! NSMutableDictionary

    self.postImageStringUrl = snapshotValue["postImageStringUrl"] as! String
    self.department = snapshotValue["department"] as! String
    self.content = snapshotValue["content"] as! String
    self.username = snapshotValue["username"] as! String
    self.postId = snapshotValue["postId"] as! String
    self.key = snapshot.key
    self.ref = snapshot.ref


}

func toAnyObject() -> [String: AnyObject] {

    return ["postImageStringUrl": postImageStringUrl as AnyObject, "department": department as AnyObject,"content": content as AnyObject,"username": username as AnyObject, "postId": postId as AnyObject]
}`

}

Any help will be greatly appreciated...Ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Posts init is

```
init(
   postImageStringUrl: String,
   department: String, 
   content: String, 
   username: String,
   postId: String, 
   key: String = "")
```

and it appears you are trying to initialize it with

```
let post = Posts(
          postImageStringUrl: String (describing: metadata!.downloadURL()), 
          content: descriptionTextView.text, 
          postId: postId)
```

Basically just missing a couple of parameters in the initialization; department, username

Comment: your so right!!! thank you...i was trying not to use department, content  && username I didn't realize it had to be there

Comment: @RubenFranco Excellent! Glad I could help. Be sure to accept the answer so it can help others!